# How can I check request body has a key or not in postman tests

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm trying to write postman tests. I want to check response according to request so I want to know what requestBody has. requestbody is a json like

```
{"subscription":{"supi":"value","gpsi":"value","pei":"value"}}.
```

This 3 elements(supi,gpsi,pei) is optional so I want to check which one exist in requestBody. I can access supi's value if it is exist with below code.

`requestBody = JSON.parse(pm.request.body); var subscription= requestBody.subscription; var supi=subscription.supi;`

I try to control if supi exists or not with `if(subscription.supi !== null)`. As I understand when supi is not in requestBody, subscription.supi does not return null so my if check doesnt work properly. How can I control supi is exist or not in requestBody?

Comment: `Object.keys(subscription).includes(checkingKeyName)` >:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript if a object property is not present it will return undefined

so use

```
   if(subscription.supi !== undefined).
```

Or you can also use

```
  Object.keys(subscription).includes(supi)
```

This will extract all keys and check it has the key supi

You can also use

```
 subscription.hasOwnProperty('supi')
```

This will check the subscription has the property supi and this is the best way